# edittext align left

Tags: java, android

I'm constructing an a sudokusolver-app for android phones.

The user is initially presented with a startpage where he/she is asked to type in the board dimension (4*4, 6*6 etc). Afterwards a new activity is started and a board with the chosen dimensions is drawn. This board consists of squares in the shape of `EditText` areas. I'm struggling with aligning the text on the left side of the `EditText` area. The text typed in the `EditText` area aligns slightly to the left but I want the text to be positioned in the corner. How do I do this? Im only using javacode, not xml

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import sudoku.androis.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SudokuUI extends Activity{

    int dim;
    EditText[][] board;
    ScrollView sv;
    RelativeLayout ll;
    int params;
    int boxHeight;
    int boxWidth;
    int textSize;
    Button neste;
    Button første;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dim = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(dim + "*" + dim + " brett");

        if(dim == 4) {
            params = 100;
            boxHeight = 2;
            boxWidth = 2;
            textSize = 20;
        }
        else if(dim == 6) {
            params = 70;    
            boxHeight = 2;
            boxWidth = 3;
            textSize = 20;
            }
        else if (dim == 9) {
            params = 50;    
            boxHeight = 3;
            boxWidth = 3;
            textSize = 12;
        }
        else if (dim == 12) {
            params = 40;
            boxHeight = 3;
            boxWidth = 4;
            textSize = 5;
        }
        else if(dim == 16){
            params = 30;
            boxHeight = 4;
            boxWidth = 4;
            textSize = 2;
        }

        sv = new ScrollView(this);
        ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ll.addView(textview);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background1));
        //ll.addView(sv);

        board = new EditText[dim][dim];
        for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {              
                board[i][j] = createEditText();
                //board[i][j].setTextSize(textSize);
                board[i][j].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.square));
                board[i][j].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams marginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(board[i][j].getLayoutParams());
                int paramOne = 0;
                int paramTwo = 0;
                for(int b = 1; b <= boxHeight; b++) {
                    for(int c = 1; c <= boxWidth; c++) {
                        if(i == boxWidth*b){
                            paramOne = 6;
                        } else if(j == boxHeight*c) {
                            paramTwo = 6;
                        }
                    }
                }
                marginParams.setMargins((i)*params + paramOne, (j+1)*params + paramTwo,0,0);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                board[i][j].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                ll.addView(board[i][j]);
            }
        }
        neste = createNesteButton();
        neste.setText("Neste");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonPar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(neste.getLayoutParams());
        buttonPar.setMargins(220,550,0,0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonPar);
        neste.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        ll.addView(neste);

        første = createNesteButton();
        første.setText("Start");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonPar2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(første.getLayoutParams());
        buttonPar2.setMargins(0,550,0,0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonPar2);
        første.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
        ll.addView(første);

        første.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int[][] numbers = new int[dim][dim];
                for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {

                        try {

                            numbers[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(board[i][j].getText().toString());
                            validNumber(Integer.parseInt(board[i][j].getText().toString()));

                        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                            numbers[i][j] = 0;

                        } catch (TooHighNumberException te) {
                            numbers[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        ll.addView(sv);
        setContentView(ll);

    }


    public EditText createEditText(){

        final LayoutParams lparams;
        lparams = new LayoutParams(params,params);
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
        edittext.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        return edittext;
    }
    public Button createNesteButton() {

        final LayoutParams lparams;
        lparams = new LayoutParams(200, 80);
        final Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        return b;
    }

    public void validNumber(int nr) throws TooHighNumberException {

        if(nr > dim || nr < 0) {
            throw new TooHighNumberException();
        }
    }

}

class TooHighNumberException extends Exception{ }
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code of what you have so far, and maybe some pictures as to what is currently happening and what you'd like to happen? This will greatly improve our understanding of the situation thus speeding up the answers.

Comment: try the solution i gave, if it doesnt work..then please paste you xml or code here..

Answer (score 1):

Set the EditText property, **In Eclipse, using the Property tab, set the Gravity to left of the EditText.**

```
android:gravity = "left";
```